# Issue with cx_oracle and oracle database api call from python program

Tags: python, oracle, api, cx-oracle

The section of the code is mentioned below and tried executing the code.

```
 typ=con.gettype('DME_FLAG_NAME_COLL')
    var3=typ.newobject()
    cur.execute("""declare
                     X_RETURN_STATUS VARCHAR2(4000);
                     X_MSG_COUNT NUMBER;
                     X_MSG_DATA  VARCHAR2 (4000); 
                     flagname DME_FLAG_NAME_COLL;
                   begin
                     DME_PUB_FLAG_NAME.GetFlagNames
                       ( P_API_VERSION =>1,
                         P_INIT_MSG_LIST => CDR_PUB_DEF_CONSTANTS.G_FALSE,
                         P_COMMIT => CDR_PUB_DEF_CONSTANTS.G_FALSE,
                         P_VALIDATION_LEVEL => CDR_PUB_DEF_CONSTANTS.G_VALID_LEVEL_FULL,
                         X_RETURN_STATUS =>:X_RETURN_STATUS,
                         X_MSG_COUNT =>X_MSG_COUNT,
                         X_MSG_DATA =>X_MSG_DATA,
                         PI_CATEGORY_ID => NULL,
                         PI_SUBJECT_VISIT => NULL,
                         PI_USER_SETTABLE => NULL,
                         PO_FLAG_NAMES => :flagname
                        ); 
                        
                   end; """, x_return_status=var, flagname=var3)
                   
    #print(var.getvalue())
    i=var3.first()
    print(var3.getelement(i))
```

The output i am getting is "<cx_Oracle.Object APPS.DME_FLAG_NAME_TYPE at -0x13dd4310>". Could someone help to clear the issue. Also tried using  "var3.getelement(i).fieldname", but says "AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.Object' object has no attribute"

Note: DME_FLAG_NAME_COLL is object type which is a table of another object type.
PO_FLAG_NAMES (out parameter)
the code works fine in Oracle (plsql)

Executed the program (section code is mentioned above ) and expecting the correct values as output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not getting the value using the statement " print(var3.getelement(i)) " . When I use this statement I am getting the object name as output "<cx_Oracle.Object APPS.DME_FLAG_NAME_TYPE at -0x13dd4310>" .

Comment: Try printing with the object dumper from the cx_Oracle tutorial: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/tutorial/type_input.py#L59-L78

Comment: Thanks Christopher Jones the object dumper (dumpobject) worked.  Appreciated ....